# Mysql after insert trigger is giving error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have written below after insert trigger and it didnt give me any error. But whenever I am trying to insert data into sept18.test I am getting below error

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'test' in stored function/trigger
>   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger. 0.000 sec

Can someone please help me with this error. Thank you in adavance.

```
-- SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME =  'TR_ORDERS_INS'
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_ORDERS_INS;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ORDERS_INS
AFTER INSERT ON sept18.test for each row 
BEGIN
DECLARE MAX_DATE1 DATETIME;
IF EXISTS 
(
select 1 from ept18.test O
where O.STOREID = NEW.STOREID
AND O.ITEMID = NEW.ITEMID
AND O.ORDERDATE = NEW.ORDERDATE
)
THEN

    SET MAX_DATE1  = (SELECT max(DateTimeStamp) 
                        from sept18.test
                        where itemid = NEW.itemid
                        and storeid = NEW.storeid
                        and OrderDate = NEW.orderdate); 

    INSERT INTO sep18kentest.orders_history 
    (ORDERID,STOREID,ITEMID,ORDERDATE,QUANTITY,BONUSBUCK,FLATBONUSBUCK,PRICE,STOREPRICE,PRICEOVERRIDE,
    PRICEOVERRIDEFLAG,DIRECTSHIPFLAG,FREEITEMFLAG,SRP,DATETIMESTAMP,RECORDNUMBER)
    SELECT ORDERID,STOREID,ITEMID,ORDERDATE,QUANTITY,BONUSBUCK,FLATBONUSBUCK,PRICE,STOREPRICE,PRICEOVERRIDE,
    PRICEOVERRIDEFLAG,DIRECTSHIPFLAG,FREEITEMFLAG,SRP,DATETIMESTAMP,RECORDNUMBER
    FROM sept18.test OD
    WHERE OD.storeid = NEW.storeid
        and OD.itemid = NEW.itemid
        and OD.orderdate = NEW.orderdate
        and OD.DateTimeStamp  < MAX_DATE1;

   DELETE FROM  sept18.test
   WHERE storeid = NEW.storeid
        and itemid = NEW.itemid
        and orderdate = NEW.orderdate       
        and DateTimeStamp  < MAX_DATE1; 

   END IF;

END$$
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is. MySQL does not allow a trigger to modify the contents of any table involved in the statement that triggered the trigger.

Comment: This seems like the kind of work you should do in your app, not in a trigger.

Comment: Hello Ueerdo, Thank you. so, how can I modify the content of a table on which there is already a trigger. It did work in sql server though. Please help. Its urgent for me.